# Custom storage backend for JanusGraph

Tags: mongodb, janusgraph

I am planning to implement a mongoDB storage backend for JanusGraph. The reason for picking MongoDB is mainly because all of our existing infrastructure and services use MongoDB, so it would be less net new maintenance requirement. Where do I get started? Is there a list of APIs that JanusGraph provides that need to be implemented by a custom backend? I couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm considering the same and doing some research too.

Answer (score -1):

As of now Janusgraph supports only limited number of storage-backends as of now (Cassandra, HBase, BigTable, Berkeley). You can find more info here https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/.